# How do mantras works?

Tags: shiva, mantras, prayer

I am practicing the mantra "om namo vagawate rudrays" this days, but although i feel the peace inside after chanting them for few minutes like 15-20 minutes with full devotion. My mind keeps asking myself, how is this possible that god named rudra can hear my chanting? As i have understood till now gods are some kind of instrument to reach the devine or fulfill some material desires, or some kind of natural forces.

But my question is how does this unconcious things listen to someones chanting? are gods concious beings who can hear someones prayer? What is the logic or this is just a belief?

Comment: Mantras work by triggering certain Nadis in our body !! Mantras are basically vibrations that act on our body in Nadis and Chakras

Comment: ok than why to use the sentence i bow to lord rudra which have a meaning, instead of using only those sounds which has affect ?

Comment: user @Username to reply. There's a process and procedure for everything. Mantras have tantras in it. Which direction to face while reciting, how to recite, what are the process one has to carry out before we start mantra reciting etc...

Comment: Mantras are based on chandas and ultimately made up of letters and swaras. The swaras and chandas and letter's also is having divine origin and are related with Creation. If chanted properly all these invoke certain aspect of brahman ,which we call god who is responsible for certain role in this Creation. Also Purva-Mimansa thinks that deities are mantra baddha i.e. they exsist in mantras.

Comment: @Dinesh Shouldn't it be "om namo bhagavate rudraya" instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions:

1. **how does an unconscious thing listens  to my someones chanting? Are Gods conscious beings who can hear someone's prayer?**

   If you believe in the Scriptures, God is Consciousness and bliss Himself- -Sat-Chit-Ananda Swarupa.

   Mandukyopanishad (6)says:

   > "Esha Sarveswara esha Sarvajna eso anntaryami" meaning that God is All-knowing and Knows the minds of all.

Gita (18/61)also says:

> "Iswarah sarvabhutanaam hriddeshe arjuna tisthati" meaning God resides in the heart of all beings.

So God is always conscious of everything and watching, listening and knowing everything.

2. What are the mantras? According to our scriptures, matra is the "Vaikhari" form, that is one form, of God. So Mantras are known as the Vangmoyee tanu (form expressed as words of God. So NO ONE EXCEPT SHIVA CAN CREATE MANTRAS. (Reference: M-karbaba, Omkarnath Rachanavali, chapter 7). So, Kularnavatantra (17/34) says:

   > japa destoys sins of thousand previous births and reveals God.
3. **You wrote you feel peace inside.**

This is supported by the vachanas of many scriptures.Shiva-Purana says:

> "Tamasontarvahirnaasho prashantih parigiyate".

ie When our inner darkness is removed, we feel peace of mind.(Dikshasaara, page 225)

In manrayogasamhita, Vrihannilatantra,Gandharvatantra, Mantramahodadhi and Kularnavatantra unianimously declares :

> "Anandashruni pulako" ( tears of joy and feeling bliss), "manah prasadah santoshah ( peace of mind and bliss) are effect of chanting mantra correctly ( Deektshasaara, page 263).

4. **You asked : What is the logic or its just the belief?** Yes, there is. But spiritulal logic. That one has to understand and experience yourself. We read in biographies of so many saints all these to be true.

But as Rickross righly said, Guru is needed for proper guidance in mantrasadhana.There are other important indications like jyoti, naada, visions etc that indicate that you are on the right track.

Answer (score 5):

It is not surprising that it is working and you are realizing the benefits.

Because, according to Tantras, there is no difference whatsoever between Devata and his Mantra.

> **YathA devas tathA mantro** yathA mantras tathA guruh |
>  Deva mantra
>   gurunAncha pujAyAh sadrisham phalam ||
>
> **What is deity that is Mantra** and that is Guru. Worship of any of those
>   three yield the same fruit.
>
> **KulArnava Tantram 13.65**

And, the previous verse says:

> YathA ghatshcha kalasah kumbhaishcha ekArtha vAchakah |
>  TathA
>   devashcha mantrascha guruschai ekArtha uchaitye ||
>
> Just as Ghata, Kalasa and Kumbha denote the same pot likewise the
>   three words - DevatA, Mantra and Guru - are synonymns.

However, according to scriptures, before chanting Mantras one should get qualified first by getting initiation from the Guru.

Comment: I hv found the mantra in one Brahmana of the Vedas @ParthaBanerjee

Comment: This mantra is dedicated to Lord Shiva and not to any one of the other Rudras .. @ParthaBanerjee It is from Taitiriya Brahmana