# Mantra And Its Mechanisms

Tags: mantras, tantra, durga, yantra, chinnamasta

I have recently gone through a couple of books on mantra, yantra, tantra, and I got to know that all these things are pure science, and not mere superstitions.

My question is, how does a mantra work?

What is the mechanism behind it?

***Note: I don't propose to seek a scientific explanation, as science can never explain the divine phenomena.***

Comment: We have already similar questions (like - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32499/how-do-mantras-works). So this Q might turn out to be a duplicate. Please search the site for similar questions and answers.

Comment: BTW do not delete the Q if its marked as a duplicate.

Comment: You say you "got to know that all these things are pure science", but then ask how they work and what the mechanism is.  How can you *know* they are pure science without first having an understanding of the basics?

Comment: @RayButterworth I have heard a lot of people taking it to be superstitious,  needed to firstly clarify the fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mantra when obtained from a competent Guru purifies one's mind eventually leading to moksha. How does that work? Prolonged meditation leads to accumulation of spiritual energy. A Guru with such a storehouse of energy transfers a portion of his energy when initiating a disciple with a mantra. When a disciple repeats such a mantra his mind is purified by that energy transferred by the Guru.

> Among the Vedic sacred formulas, the Gayatri has been prescribed for
> repetition from ancient times. The Vedic people had great faith in the
> efficacy of mantras. The Mimamsakas considered mantras to be the
> embodiments of deities. In fact, they accepted no deities other than
> the mantras at all. To them Brahman is nothing but sound (shabda), and
> sound produces form. Thus, the name embodied in the mantra is more
> real than the form of the deity. ....
>
> Forms are made up of nothing but
> fine vibrations, and vibrations are produced by sound only, so these
> ancient conceptions are tenable. From another point of view, a mantra
> gains spiritual potency through many years of being associated with
> holy men who have repeated it and attained realization through it. The
> concept of the mantra is based on the psychological fact that much of
> our thinking depends on auditory symbols. Repetition of the mantra
> creates a chain of thought which induces the mind with the thought of
> God, and this is the aim of all spiritual practices.
>
> .................
>
> Every Vedic mantra has a rishi who first intuited it, a particular
> metre in which it is composed, and a deity to whom it is addressed. In
> Tantric mantras the most important element is the vija, a sacred
> syllable considered to be charged with spiritual potency, as also
> Shakti or power and a kilaka, a pillar (inner syllables on which the
> mantra rests.) All the letters of the Sanskrit alphabets are
> considered as different matrikas, minor deities around the main deity.
> The mantra is charged with a special potency, so much so that the
> Tantrikas believe that when offerings are made to the deity with the
> appropriate mantras, the deity accepts them immediately.
>
> .........
>
> The
> Chandogya Upanishad I.1.10 says about the efficacy of the repetition
> of Om: Both perform spiritual practices - he who knows and he who does
> not know. But knowledge and ignorance are different in their effects.
> Whatever is performed with knowledge, faith and meditation, becomes
> spiritually effective.

**Meditation and other spiritual disciplines by Swami Swahananda**

Comment: Thanks a lot!:)